# Prevent GRUB from showing up by default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, boot-loader, grub-legacy

Whenever I boot on Ubuntu, I see the entire GRUB menu by default. Is there a way I could make it simply auto-boot if uninterrupted within X seconds? I remember that this was the case on previous releases of Ubuntu, it would only show the GRUB menu if you held down a button during the boot.

How can I make GRUB do this by default and just get on with the boot process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using GRUB.

With GRUB 1 (GRUB legacy, versions 0.9x), in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, type in `hiddenmenu`. Press ESC key to show the menu.

```
#General configuration:
#Uninterupted within 5 seconds and default boot option 0.
timeout   5
default   0
color light-blue/black light-cyan/blue

#Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
hiddenmenu
```

If you are using GRUB 2 (versions 1.9x and up), `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` contains the menu. But to change settings, edit the `/etc/default/grub` file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on GRUB2. Thanks, I think it's because I had to install GRUB to a specific partition and not to the drive itself due to EFI.

Answer (score 1):

Odd that it's not already in there, it still is for me.  Anyway, add this to your `/boot/grub/menu.lst`:

```
timeout 5
default 0
```

That sets grub to boot the first entry after five seconds.  If you prefer the second, third, etc. entry in your grub configuration, change `0` accordingly.

If you want something other than the newest kernel, you may need to check that the number is still correct after updating the kernel.

Comment: That's for Grub 1, which is not the default bootloader on current Ubuntu version (it's the default on Ubuntu 10.04 which is still supported but is two LTS versions behind).